# web developer bootcamp : iterating over an array with JS

Tags: javascript

The problem asks to change the 7 spans through selecting all the spans and then changing the color of each of them. Im seeing that this solution works. And also there was another way I found. However, is there any way I can make this solution without a nested for loop? I feel like I'm missing something about using arrays or something. Thanks.

```
const colors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'indigo', 'violet']; //PLEASE DON'T CHANGE THIS LINE!

`enter code here`//YOU CODE GOES HERE:
const spanners = document.querySelectorAll('span');
for( i = 0 ; i < colors.length ; i++){
    for(let span of spanners){
        span.style.color = colors[i]
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're doing `i++` for every colour, _times_ every span. It's inside both loops

Comment: `.querySelectorAll()` returns a `NodeList`, which has a `.forEach()` method, that passes the current element and index to the callback. Check the examples on [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach)

Answer (score 0):

If there are 7 colours and 7 spans, you can just do :

```
const colors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'indigo', 'violet'];

const spanners = document.querySelectorAll('span');

for( let i in colors){
    spanners[i].style.color = colors[i];
}
```

Comment: `for...in...` is for objects and not arrays

Comment: Try `for( let i in ['red', 'orange', 'yellow']) console.log(i)` in your console. Day not wasted, you learned something :)

Comment: `for...in...` will return index of i and `for...of...` will return element

Comment: I know it works. But this doesn't change the original purpose of [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) which is to iterate over the properties (including those from the prototype chain) of an object

Comment: [Why is using “for…in” for array iteration a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-for-array-iteration-a-bad-idea)

Comment: Meh, so long as it works. Day not wasted, I learned something. Thanks